# Scene crashes in Editor, only sometimes, when loading scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

My scene loads fine in the Editor maybe 50% of the time.  The other half the time Unity stops responding and I have to kill the application.  This is also the case when I cause the scene to reload while the Editor is already in play mode.  The log doesn't give any useful information as far I can tell, but I've posted it below.  What else can I do to see why my scene is crashing?

> Reloading assemblies for play mode. 
>   Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
>   Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v2018.3.9 for Unity v2018.3.9f1
>   Registering platform support modules:
>   Registered platform support modules in: 0.0554295s.
>   Native extension for Android target not found
>   Native extension for iOS target not found
>   Native extension for OSXStandalone target not found
>   Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 1.64 ms, found 2 plugins.
>   Preloading 1 native plugins for Editor in 1.15 ms.
>   Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
>   - Completed reload, in  1.489 seconds
>   Platform modules already initialized, skipping
>   Load scene 'Temp/__Backupscenes/0.backup' time: 0.616473 ms

Comment: Does this happen with all scenes in your project? Or with some specific ones? Did you try to create a empty one and check if this happen?
You can check if there is a broken prefab in the scene, this tends to break scene load in editor.

Comment: It's only my main game scene (it's a 1 scene small game).  The preloader scene runs fine.  The game runs fine 50% of the time in the Editor, and 100% of the time once installed on my iPhone, so I'm having trouble locating the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what call was breaking the Editor by running the game repeatedly until the freeze occurred, then using Visual Studio (MonoDevelop would also work) and going to Run -> Attach to Process, and then pausing to identify the last call made.  In my case it was a while loop which could sometimes cause an overflow with unlucky randomization.